# How to configure HAProxy according to request based on ports on same IP?

Tags: nginx, haproxy

I Have Two Background server

Website-1. 192.168.1.10:80

Website-2. 192.168.1.10:8080

I have to use haproxy as gateway for accessing it through same URL, Difference is that website-2 access through Port No Putting it manually after ip.

( I want This Both on SSL, Http to HTTPS Redirections)
Haproxy IP : 192.168.1.11

Scenario 1.

client enters 192.168.1.10 it redirects to https:192.168.1.10

192.168.1.11 ---> https:192.168.1.11 (backend 192.168.1.11)

Scenario 2.

client enters 192.168.1.10:8080 it redirects to https:192.168.1.10:8080

192.168.1.11:8080 ---> https:192.168.1.11:8080 (backend 192.168.1.11:8080)

How can i achieve This situations using Haproxy Or nginx

Comment: Where are you terminating SSL, on HAProxy or the backends? What have you tried so far?

Comment: If possible i want to terminate it on haproxy

Comment: Can you post your current config?

Comment: for nginx i achieve this one for haproxy iw ill required